# How to load javascript in windows 8

Tags: c#, windows, internet-explorer, microsoft-metro

I am looking for a way to implement Internet explorer - a desktop version in my Winodws 8 app . This is caused by my c# application- i need to run javascript page but its impossible in metro version of IE. Is there any method to do this? 
I `ll describe my problem: when i want to load html of DOM page(rendered by javascript) i cant because javascript can run (I use WebView). I tried to open this page using Desktop version and it worked perfectly. Unfortunately Metro IE10 cant show the content and my WebView too. 
Thanks for help.

Comment: Could you give an example of a javascript that doesn't run?

Comment: What does the HTML look like? could it be that you're relying on a plugin? Plain old Javascript should be fine (after all, Stack Overflow works)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I need to parse this : http://open.fm/play/2 to read source of square image  and all other strings. But i cant open it  with metro IE, html source contains no useful data.

Answer (score 0):

You can sure inject in the c# webview a javascript file:
This is the action for a button:

```
private async void Lamp_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Uri uri = new Uri("ms-appx:///js/injected.js");
    StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(uri);
    string text = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(file); //reading content as string
    var script = "(function(){" + text + "})()";
}

try
{
    var result = wv.InvokeScript("eval", new string[] { script });
}
catch (Exception) { }
```

**wv** is you id name for the webview element in the xaml

Comment: Thanks. Could you tell me if I can set Uri as an http adress?